# In the international law, is there any law or a principle regulating treaties signed with a state that later broke up?

Tags: international-law

In the international law, is there any law or a principle regulating such cases like which resulting state must be a successor to the state that has just broken up and how the signed treaties with that non-existing-now state must be continued?

Comment: This is in danger of getting circular, since a lot of what international law there is is codified in treaties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I think what you are looking for is the [Vienna Convention on Succession of States in respect of Treaties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_Convention_on_Succession_of_States_in_respect_of_Treaties)

**Disclaimer** Please note that this convention is not ratified by many states, however it seems to represent a consensus of learned persons assembled under the auspices of the UN and based on "customary" treatment of these matters.   Don't assume any of it can be enforced.

This information is offered for educational and entertainment value only.